# Twitter Auth with Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, twitter, authentication

What is the best twitter auth plugin for Django. I do not understand why django-social-auth and django socialregistration suck so badly, but authentication to both facebook + twitter is not that hard and there seems to be no good django packages for either.

Please prove me wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What specifically are your problems with `django-social-auth` and `django-socialregistration`? "suck so badly" is not a sufficient description for people to know what you will think is "best".

Comment: Plus, if it's so easy, why don't you do it yourself?

Comment: I like django-social-auth (not to be confused with django-socialauth). There are docs and tests. It's actively maintained and the author is very responsive to issues on Github.

Comment: i did do it myself for facebook, but i do not feel like having to maintain an auth backend everytime facebook changes their APIs. Ill take back everything I said about either of these apps if you can great a project on github that uses both of them successfully. They are a HUGE pain in the ass to try to use.

Comment: mark, can you provide an open-source example of a project that is using django-socialauth?

Comment: Joseph, there is an example in the project repo https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example. As for my work I use it on BrewedByUs.com but it is not open source.

Answer (score 2):

I've attempted using [allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/), but haven't gotten it to work.

This post lead me to it:
http://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/review-of-4-django-social-auth-apps/

Let us know what you find that works.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tested django-social-auth and django-socialregistration and they sucked. Things like easily fixed AttributeErrors caused by the software not being kept up to date with the latest Django. They also build upon the model that you authenticate with any of the social auth provider, but you still have to create a new account to login.

Then I tried [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) and it is the best thing since sliced bread. You can either use it standalone because it is not so hard to integrate its javascript and json api yourself from scratch. Or use [django-rpx-plus](https://github.com/mikexstudios/django-rpx-plus) (RPX is the old name for Janrain) that provides some views and data structures to make integration even easier.

Using Janrain, it is easy to just let your users click on the google/twitter/facebook icon, click accept on the providers page shown in a popup and voila! logged in! The only downsides are the Janrain branding shown in the free version and that you have to rely on a third party for authentication.